# npm install returns 401 unauthorized on one of my packages

Tags: node.js, github, npm, npm-install

I have a GitHub account where I have projects and components. One of my projects includes a separate NPM component from the same GitHub account.

I am working on Windows with git. I have connected GitHub via SSH and I can `git pull` / `push` etc. I have also created a non-expiring personal access token in GitHub and added to local.

My `.npmrc` contains:

```
//npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=ghp_MY_TOKEN
@org-name:registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com/
```

When I run `npm install` I end up with:

```
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/@org-name%2fpackage-name - Your request could not be authenticated by the GitHub Packages service. Please ensure your access token is valid and has the appropriate scopes configured.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-11-06T23_35_02_955Z-debug.log
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Perhaps it's the scope of the token? Does it have the "read:packages" scope?

Comment: Hi yes. I gave this token (my personal one, and I am the owner of the org and repos) all scopes